# TreeView with FileSystemModel-like Functionality?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to get a QTreeView to function like it would with a QFileSystemModel, a folder hierarchy in which you can browse sub elements for that particular node. The only problem is I want it to be based on string data, such as using a list of strings "my/path/file.ext". I've tried using QStringListModel but it simply put them all on the same level.

Comment: Please always share your code what you have tried.

Comment: @LaszloPapp QTreeView::setModel(QStringListModel(mylistofstrings)) effectively, is all there is. Not very informative is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `QStringListModel` provides a list of strings, not a tree of strings. It doesn't interpret the strings in any way.

You could reuse the `QStandardItemModel`. A `QStandardItem` is already a tree node. A class like below can be used to insert your paths into a `QStandardItemModel`.

```
class TreeManipulator {
  Q_DISABLE_COPY(TreeManipulator)
  static QChar const m_sep;
  QMap<QString, QStandardItem*> m_items;
  QStandardItem * m_root;
  QString normalizedPath(const QString & path) {
    QStringList p(path.split(m_sep, QString::SkipEmptyParts));
    return p.join(sep);
  }
  QStandardItem * find(QStandardItem * item, const QString & child) {
    for (int i = 0; i < item->rowCount(); ++i)
      if (item->child(i)->text() == child) return item->child(i);
    return nullptr;
  }
public:
  explicit TreeManipulator(QStandardItem * root) : m_root(root) {}
  explicit  TreeManipulator(QStandardItemModel * model) : 
    m_root(model->invisibleRootItem()) {}
  QStandardItem * find(QString path) const {
    path = normalizedPath(path);
    if (m_items.contains(path)) return m_items[path];
    return nullptr;
  }
  QStandardItem * addItem(QString path) {
    QStandardItem * item = m_root;
    QStringList p(path.split(m_sep, QString::SkipEmptyParts));
    path = normalizedPath(path);
    if (m_items.contains(path)) return m_items[path];
    while (!p.isEmpty()) {
      QString elt = p.takeFirst();
      QStandardItem * child = find(item, elt);
      if (!child)
        item.appendRow((child = new QStandardItem(elt)));
      item = child;
    }
    m_items.insert(path, item);
    return item;
  }
};

QChar const TreeManipulator::m_sep(QLatin1Char('/'));
```